Movie about a girl being cursed (demonic?) she gets really attached to this church girl who ends up trying to drown her
The beginning starts out with this girl getting scared from her boyfriend in this creepy barn but they started making out and her dad comes up and takes her away and I think the car crashes and he stabs his daughter and kills her. Then the movie actually starts that has to do with this other girl who's mom was recently put in a mental institution for trying to kill her and the girl is having some strange things happening to her lately and is going to be claimed or something. Apparently her mom made a deal with the devil to save her life or something. She befriends this church girl to get help somehow and the girl ends up trying to drown her instead of baptize her in the church pool. All I know is at the end it got too late and she went with the boy and joined this weird demonic clan.

The Haunting of Molly Hartley. It match what you described perfectly



